# Chat plugin for WordPress which can show user IPs when I am logged in as admin

Tags: chat, wordpress

I would like to install a chat for my WordPress blog, so users would be able to chat with each other or the actual admin.

On my blog admins often need to know the user IP to make actions on the server (add IP to allowed users, kick user, ban user, etc.), so I would like to use a chat plugin which is capable to show the guest user IPs too when the admin is logged into WordPress blog.

Of course users will not see each other's IP addresses. Till now I am using **iFlyChat plugin**, it is pretty good, but admins always have to login to the plugin dashboard on the official website of [iFlyChat](https://iflychat.com/) to see the user IP addresses.